# Unable to get storage account using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to get the storage account to create blob container and I am getting parameter cannot be found error in PowerShell

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The command whatever using as per your image is correct, but you first need to provide the storage name and then give the context details this way you won't get the error mentioned in screenshot*

[image]